# How come the zkemkeeper SDK OnConnected event doesn't fire?

Tags: c#, events

I have a facial recognition device. There is an SDK of this device. I use it to send commands to the device, but it doesn't fire some events. The onConnected and OnDisconnected functions are not fired, but the onAttendanceTransaction function is being called. Why are the other functions not called?

**The code:**

```
  public void init()
    {
        Thread machineActionListener = new Thread(() =>
        {
            connect();
            Application.Run();
        });

        machineActionListener.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        machineActionListener.Start();
    }

    private CZKEMClass getDeviceApi()
    {
        if(deviceApi == null)
        {
            deviceApi = new CZKEMClass();
        }
        return deviceApi;
    }

    private void connect()
    {
        Logger.log("Connecting to ...", machine.getMachineInfo());
        Boolean isConnected = getDeviceApi().Connect_Net(this.machine.ip, this.machine.port);
        if (isConnected)
        {
            connectionTryCount = 0;
            Logger.log("Connected!");

            if (getDeviceApi().RegEvent(this.machine.machineCode, 65535))
            {
                getDeviceApi().OnAttTransactionEx += new _IZKEMEvents_OnAttTransactionExEventHandler(onAttendanceTransaction);
                getDeviceApi().OnConnected += new _IZKEMEvents_OnConnectedEventHandler(onConnected);
                getDeviceApi().OnDisConnected += new _IZKEMEvents_OnDisConnectedEventHandler(onDisConnected);

            }
        }
        else
        {
            Logger.log("Could not be connected! Reconnecting...", machine.getMachineInfo());
            if(connectionTryCount < Config.CONNECTION_TRY_LIMIT)
            {
                connectionTryCount++;
                connect();
            }
            else
            {
                Logger.logAndMail("Cihaza " + Config.CONNECTION_TRY_LIMIT + " connection limit exceed!",
                    "Cihaz Bilgileri: " + machine.getMachineInfo());
            }
        }
    }

    private void onConnected()
    {
        Logger.log("Connected to device: " + machine.getMachineInfo());
    }

    private void onDisConnected()
    {
        Logger.log("Disconnected from device: " + machine.getMachineInfo());
        connect();
    }
```

Comment: Do you have a link to the SDK in question? The closest I could find on Google was [this NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ZKemkeeper/).

Comment: http://www.zkteco.eu/index.php/downloads/software-downloads

Comment: Any idea about this?

Comment: To be honest, I don't use this SDK, and your link does not appear to have any documentation available. I am personally limited in my ability to help due to this, so you might have to wait for someone with more experience with this SDK to come along and take a look. If I had to take a wild guess, I would check whether the `OnConnected` and `OnDisConnected` events are actually being fired in the first place (are these the actual event names, or event handlers themselves?).

Comment: Another idea: You call `getDeviceApi()` several times in a row in your `connect` function definition. See if you can store its result in a variable and perform your method calls on that as opposed to re-calling it each time you need it.

Answer (score 1):

Try it:

```
        private void connect()
{
    Logger.log("Connecting to ...", machine.getMachineInfo());

    getDeviceApi().OnConnected += new _IZKEMEvents_OnConnectedEventHandler(onConnected);
    getDeviceApi().OnDisConnected += new _IZKEMEvents_OnDisConnectedEventHandler(onDisConnected);

    Boolean isConnected = getDeviceApi().Connect_Net(this.machine.ip, this.machine.port);
    if (isConnected)
    {
        connectionTryCount = 0;
        Logger.log("Connected!");

        if (getDeviceApi().RegEvent(this.machine.machineCode, 65535))
        {
            getDeviceApi().OnAttTransactionEx += new _IZKEMEvents_OnAttTransactionExEventHandler(onAttendanceTransaction);
        }
    }
}
```

RegEvent -> Register events by masks:

- 1 **OnAttTransaction, OnAttTransactionEx**
- 2 **OnFinger**
- 4 **OnNewUser**
- 8 **OnEnrollFinger**
- 16 **OnKeyPress**
- 256 **OnVerify**
- 512 **OnFingerFeature**
- 1024 **OnDoor, OnAlarm**
- 2048 **OnHIDNum**
- 4096 **OnWriteCard**
- 8192 **OnEmptyCard**
- 16384 **OnDeleteTemplate**

Events OnConnected() and OnDisConnected() work without RegEvent()
and adding before connecttion

Comment: I have check this answer already on stackoverflow but this is also not working.